# shift altgr combination for console keymap

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, console, openrc, virtual-consoles

I am using Artix Linux with OpenRC.

I want to define a custom console keymap to generally use the US-design, but add some extra functionality for German umlauts. The following does work:

`/usr/share/keymaps/i386/qwerty/mymap.map`:

```
include "us.map"

altgr keycode 30 = adiaeresis
```

Activating with `rc-update add keymaps boot` /`rc-service keymaps restart` as described [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout_switching#OpenRC).

With these configurations, when I press AltGr+a, `ä` gets printed as intended.

I want to do the same for AltGr+Shift+a to produce `Ä`. However, adding the line
`shift altgr keycode 30 = Adiaeresis` to my keymap, then restarting the service yields the following error:

```
Setting keyboard mode [UTF-8] ...            [ ok ]
Loading key mappings [mymap] ...
adding map 3 violates explicit keymaps line
Error leading key mappings                   [ !! ]
ERROR: keymaps failed to start
```

What does that tell me and how can I fix it?

`altgr shift keycode 30 = Adiaeresis` has the same result.

I also tried to modify the existing line to `altgr keycode 30 = adiaeresis Adiaeresis`, but that yields `syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting EOL`.

I use [this](https://linux.die.net/man/5/keymaps) as a reference, but i find it hard to read and interpret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found an alternative way to declare it that works: the number system described in the manpage of keymaps. Note that in `/usr/share/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz` (unpacked), there is the line `keymaps 0-2,4-6,8-9,12`, ommitting 3, which is what I need (Shift+AltGr). So my file now looks like this, and that works fine:

```
include "us.map"

keymaps 0-3

keycode 22 = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode 24 = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode 30 = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode 31 = s S ssharp
```

I still don't understand the error in the question though.

Comment: Actually, you do.  You had (via inclusion) an explicit `keymaps` line stating that map 3 was being omitted from all definitions, and then you had a definition that explicitly addressed map 3, in violation of that.